# Show that $\|x\|_{1} \le n\|x\|_\infty$ for any $x \in \Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I don't know how to proof this. I know that $\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|$ and $\|x\|_\infty = max_{1\le i \le n}|x_{i}|$. In the same exercise I proved that $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2 \le \|x\|_1$ for any $x \in \Bbb R^n$, so maybe I need to use this somehow? The first thing I thought was:
$$ \|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_1 \le n\|x\|_1$$
But I don't think it follows from this that $\|x\|_1 \le n\|x\|_\infty$?

Comment: Can you do it for $n=2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|x_j| \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i|= \|x\|_{\infty}$$

Now sum over all the $j$ will give you the result

Comment: Ah of course, thank you. It's so simple and I didn't see it. :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\| x \| _1 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \vert x_i \vert \leq n\max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \vert x_i \vert = n\| x \|_{\infty}$$